# How to create custom ReactiveMongo Reader & Writer for object?

Tags: scala, playframework, play-reactivemongo

Let's say I have the following model:

```
case class Game(var _id: Option[BSONObjectID] = None,
                   name: String,
                   genre: Genre.Kind,
                   var created: Option[DateTime] = None,
                   var updated: Option[DateTime] = None
                  )
```

I want to store an instance of `Game` as follows:
`{"_id": "ObjectId(12345)", "name": "My Shooter Game", "genre": "Shooter", …}`

For `Genre` I want to store the value as a String, but programmatically I want to deal with types and not values.

So here is what I thought would work:

```
object Genre {

  sealed trait Kind

  implicit val genreJsonFormat = Json.format[Genre.Kind]

  case object Shooter extends Kind {
    val name = "Shooter"

    override def toString = name
  }

  def getGenre(genre: String) = genre match {
    case Shooter.name => Shooter
    // ...
  }

  implicit object GenreWriter extends BSONDocumentWriter[Genre.Kind] {
    def write(genre: Genre.Kind): BSONDocument =
      BSONDocument("genre" -> genre.toString)
  }

  implicit object GenreReader extends BSONDocumentReader[Genre.Kind] {
    def read(doc: BSONDocument): Genre.Kind = Genre.getGenre(doc.getAs[String]("genre").get)
  }

}
```

Unfortunately, I get this compile error:

> No unapply or unapplySeq function found

For:

```
implicit val genreJsonFormat = Json.format[Genre.Kind]
```

Any idea how I can achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

The macros from Play JSON do not yet support sealed family, so you have to do it the same way it's done for the BSON handlers.

Comment: It's recommanded to first read the [documentation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaJson)

Comment: `Json.format` is not provided by ReactiveMongo, but Play JSON